# Generate Single CSS File From Stylesheets Declared in Rails Views Without Manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I currently have view-specific stylesheets declared in my Rails Views using:

```
<% content_for :page_specific_stylesheets do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "some-stylesheet", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "some-other-stylesheet", :media => "all" %>
<% end %>
```

I also have a separate application-wide stylesheet built from Sass partials and separate stylesheets through the application.css manifest. I like having the page-specific stylesheets listed in my views, but the problem with this is that they not combined and minified, but included in the page as separate stylesheets. I know I could reference a single manifest stylesheet for the page here instead and have that reference the page-specific stylesheets, but I'd like to skip this manifest and keep the individual stylesheets declared in the view as I feel it's clearer.

So is there any way I can tell Rails/Sprockets to combine and minfy a group of stylesheets from the view. Obviously this would give me two stylesheets per page - my site-wide stylesheet and a page-specific stylesheet, but this is fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to combine files from a view, but a stylesheet can behave as a manifest. If you use the `@include` directive, Sass precompiles the it by inserting the contents of that file into the calling file.

Leave the second declaration:

```
<% content_for :page_specific_stylesheets do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "some-other-stylesheet", :media => "all" %>
<% end %>
```

and at the top of `some-other-stylesheet.css.scss`, include the first:

```
@include "some-stylesheet";

/* Other Sass... */
```

Comment: As I mention in the question I 'have a separate application-wide stylesheet built from Sass partials'. My question is can I compile a set of stylesheets together without the use of a manifest.